# Using help.search() with knitr... random error: can't establish a connection to the server

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

I'm creating a kind of tutorial for R using **knitr** from **RStudio**.

When I use the **help.search()** function, a web page is open and shows the documentation.
That's great!

However, that doesn't always work as expected and half of the times the web page returns the error:

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ...

How can I handle this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: You mean `help.start()`?

Comment: Nope. By doing some other tests, this is something that happens at random with any function that opens a web page from knitr.

Comment: Well, help.search() itself does not work -- you have to provide a keyword. That is why I was asking. You need to give a minimal reproducible example to avoid ambiguity and misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `help.search()` relies on a live R session to display the search results at, for example, `http://127.0.0.1:xxxxx`. When RStudio knits a document, it opens a new R session, knits the document, closes the R session, and displays the result document. You may not be able to see the web page because the R session might have been closed by the time when Firefox is launched.

I have added support in [the **printr** package](https://github.com/yihui/printr) for `help.search()` and `help()` (see its [package vignette](http://yihui.name/printr) for examples). However, in general, you should avoid writing *interactive* code in **knitr** documents.

Comment: You can see the complete example here: https://github.com/Diego-F-Pereira/R-Notes/blob/master/Minitutorial_01.Rmd

Comment: I did a change in my repo, and the previous link got broken... sorry. This is the updated link https://github.com/Diego-F-Pereira/R-Notes

Comment: @Diego I have finished the work now. Please see https://github.com/yihui/printr and http://yihui.name/printr Thanks!